# Messages with an attachment do not arrive in the mail?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, smtp

I am trying to send mail with attachment. Mail is sent but without attachment, i am using a `phpmailer`, and here my filling form:

```
<form id="contactForm" action="handler.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div class="field-block">
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input id="name" class="field" name="name" required type="text" placeholder="Name">
      </div

      <input type="file" name="uploaded_file" id="uploaded_file" />
  <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10000000" />

        <div>
          <input type="hidden" name="Max">
        </div>

      <button id="button" class="button" type="submit">Submit</button>
      <div class="result">
        <span id="answer"></span>
        <span id="loader"><img src="images/loader.gif" alt=""></span>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Php handler example `ContactMailer.php`:

```
<?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;

require_once __DIR__ . '/PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';

class ContactMailer
{

    private static $emailFrom = 'a*******@yandex.ru';

    private static $emailTo = 'a*******.b@gmail.com';


    public static function send($name, $email, $phone, $message, $company,$job)
    {

        $body = "Name: " . $name . "\Company:".$company."\nJob:" .$job ."\nE-mail: " . $email . "\nPhone: " . $phone . "\n\nMessage:\n" . $message;


if (isset($_FILES['uploaded_file']) &&
    $_FILES['uploaded_file']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'],
                         $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
}


        $mailer = new PHPMailer();

        $mailer->isSMTP();

        $mailer->Host = ' smtp.yandex.ru';

        $mailer->SMTPAuth = true;

        $mailer->Username = self::$emailFrom;

        $mailer->Password = '*******';

        $mailer->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';

        $mailer->Port = '465';
        $mailer->addAttachment($uploadfile, 'My uploaded file');

        $mailer->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

        $mailer->setFrom(self::$emailFrom, 'Имя отправителя');

        $mailer->addAddress(self::$emailTo);

        $mailer->isHTML(false);

        $mailer->Subject = 'Заполнена форма обратной связи';

        $mailer->Body = $body;



        if ($mailer->send()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

I set up everything according to the tutorial, but the file with the attachment is not transferred, has anyone encountered such a problem? can you help me to solve this problem?

Comment: what is the value of `$uploadfile` here ?

Comment: excuse me, what value?

Comment: `$mailer->addAttachment($uploadfile, 'My uploaded file'); ` here in this line what is the value of `$uploadfile` variable